# Kolitn Error when compile suspend functions: Cannot access built-in declaration kotlin.coroutines.SuspendFunction

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I tried to compile an old project and got the next error:

`Kotlin: Cannot access built-in declaration 'kotlin.coroutines.SuspendFunction1'. Ensure that you have a dependency on the Kotlin standard library`

I put the kotlin stdlib (`compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.2.30"`) and the kotlinx core (`compile "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:0.22.3"`) on the dependencies but the error still continues.

Anyone had this problem and managed to fix it?

````
The project uses:
- kotlinx version = 0.22.3 
- kotlin version = 1.2.30 

The version of the IntelliJ IDEA is 2019.2.3

The kotlin plugin version is 1.3.50-release-IJ2019.2-1```
````

Comment: Any reason you're using such an old version of kotlin specifically?  Kotlin `1.3` has been been available for nearly a year already and is required for general coroutine support.

Comment: I think you're trying to compile the project with IDEA plugin 1.3.50, and it can't find some stdlib declaration not available in 1.2.30 stdlib. Please try to compile the project with Gradle (from command line) with kotlin 1.2.30 or better yet, update your stdlib and coroutines to latest stable versions: 1.3.50 and 1.3.2, respectively.